# ¿Como puedo activar la accion onBackPressed solo en fragments y desactivarla en la Activity que los contiene?

Tags: android-fragment, activity, onbackpressed

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en la que manejo varias activities y fragments pero solo quiero mantener la acción de volver presionando el botón back en los fragments y no en las activities, pues si lo dejo activo no tiene sentido que use un botón de cerrar sesión si estando en la activity principal con solo presionar back se saldrá de esta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método de `onBackPressed()` es del `Activity`.

Lo que suelo hacer es tomar el evento en el activity reenviarlo al fragment que esté visible en la pantalla.

Luego el Fragment devuelve true si consume el evento o false si no lo hace.

Si el fragment consumió el evento, en el activity no hago nada. Y si el fragment no consumió el evento, entonces dejo que lo maneje el activity, por ejemplo para salir de la aplicación con finish.

En todo caso creao una interface

```
interface BackButtonListener{
   public boolean onBackPressed();
}
```

Y hago que los fragments la implementen. De esta forma el Activity puede llamar ese método sobre los fragments y recibir si el fragment hizo algo o no con el evento.

Comment: Gracias, aunque tu método no me sirvió para lo que quería hacer en este caso si me sirvió para volver entre fragmentos volviéndolos a crear sin que se sobrepusieran

Answer (score 0):

Lo que me sirvió fue de un foro en ingles y lo dejo aquí por si a alguien mas le sirve

```
public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }else{
                if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() <= 1){
                }else {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }
            }
        }
```